# Upload Powerpoint to Google Drive as file

Tags: r, google-drive-api, tidyverse

I want to upload Powerpoint files to Google drive. When I do this using the UI (clicking on "Upload File" and uploading a file), things work as I expect. However, when I use the Drive API I get some formatting issues. For example, the shading (text highlight) in my Powerpoint tables is transparent, but when I upload to Drive using the API the shading becomes white.

I have tried to work around this by specifying MIME type as `application/vnd.google-apps.file`, but when I get the response, the MIME type shows as `application/vnd.google-apps.presentation`

I am using Google Drive API v3, accessed through the R package `googledrive`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this mimeType : [**application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)
including : 
**[application/vnd.google-apps.file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)**

Here is an example done with `NodeJS`, try and let me know if it works well for you.

Just in case, try other mimeTypes (url is provided on Reference list, scroll down)

```js
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': '___Your File Name Here___',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
  body: fs.createReadStream('___Your File Name Here___.pptx')
};

function uploadFile(auth){
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  })
}

// RUN script
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {

  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  authorize(JSON.parse(content), uploadFile);

});
```

**References:**

- [Google mimeTypes (Google Reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
- [List of mimeTypes (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)